# Is it possible to get a Toshiba Satellite laptop to communicate via Bluetooth to a Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: bluetooth, toshiba-laptop, galaxy-s3

I have a Toshiba Satellite computer running Windows 7  and a Samsung Galaxy 3 phone. They both show their bluetooth is on but the laptop wont find the phone. I do not know how to get a free download to fix the problem. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

When you turn on your phone bluetooth the phone wont be automatily visable for other devices.
In most cases you will need to got to the bluetooth setting in your phone and make the phone visible for other devices.

Something like this http://shikkhar-alo501.blogspot.de/2013/04/make-bluetooth-device-discoverable-to.html